# Execute code on site creation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, feature-stapling

We're trying to create a SharePoint 2010 feature on a site collection that when active would execute code each time a web site is created. We're using Visual Studio 2010. The code will set properties on the web site (enable publishing, add some lists, set properties on the lists/libraries). We'd also settle for a console app that would do the same thing. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a Web Event Receiver to do this, and handle the 'WebProvisioned' method. This can be created as a Site collection scoped feature that will trigger for every sub website that's provisioned.

Comment: Thanks, James. Can you point me to an example of something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I have just completed something similar.  I create a new site collection based on user input for Title, owner, template, metadata defaults, set auditing and retention policies, etc.  This is done via a workflow attached to the request list 'ItemAdded' event.  I can probably break the workflow process down into digestible pieces ( it will give me incentive to write a new blog post anyway).

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Will you be posting sample code? Also, we're doing this with a new web site and not site collection, but I guess it's the same thing.

Comment: I am writing the blog entries for this as we speak.  They will be posted on 

www.stoneyowlsolutions.com/wordpress

when I complete them.